# Spring starter-validation and Validator injection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator

I've created simple non-mvc project and added spring-boot-starter-validation dependency. When I tried to Inject javax.validation.Validator I got an error `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Does it mean that spring-boot-starter-validation does not provide any default Validator i.e. `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` and I always have to create it on my own like in normal project without spring boot?

```
@Component
public class ExampleService{

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    public void someMethod(){
            //validation
    }

}
```

Injection fails and it does not matter if Validator is from javax.validation or org.springframework.validation package.

Comment: Can you please add more code and logs: what bean is missing?

Comment: I've added simplest possible example. Spring Starter Project > Validation dependency, and this simple component. Injection fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No `Beans` are provided out of the box with `spring-boot-starter-validation` hence why you are experiencing `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`

See the following [rationale](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/346392d31b978ba575ac69954d085ce35fd250a6#diff-e1a7c67f391410902088aa35ce642477) for this starter, straight from the horses mouth:

> Previously, the only starter that provided validation was
>   spring-boot-starter-web which included Hibernate Validator and
>   Tomcat's EL implementation. This left users writing non-web
>   applications to figure out the dependencies for themselves. They would
>   sometimes run into difficulties as Hibernate Validator's need for an
>   EL implementation would trip them up.
>
> This commit adds a new starter, spring-boot-starter-validation, which
>   provides both Hibernate Validator and Tomcat's EL implementation.
>   spring-boot-starter-web has been updated to depend on this starter
>   rather than depending on Hibernate Validator directly.